# Helper for visual studio 2015 for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I had a question about the editor for visualStudio. Basically, I am following along with a course for C++ and at this point, we are defining a function in a staticLib. We then proceed to call the function in the staticLib file of which the editor reminds that the include statement has not yet been declared.

I have attached screenshots for this as follows:

[image]

Notice that his microsoft visualstudio suggests that he make the `#include "../StaticLib/foo.h"`

Where mine is as follows: [image]

And I do not really get any suggestions no matter what I type. Would someone mind helping me out with this as I am relatively new to visual studio community 2015 but I find that this is really helpful as I am a java programmer who used other IDE before and such suggestions just happen automatically for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thank you

Comment: Include files are one of the more archaic and tedious parts of C++ (they hail from the '70s C...).  Even if you get that ReSharper plugin, you should learn to understand them and write them, because many bugs and especially mysterious compile errors arise from them.  Key to understanding is, includes are essentially copy-paste performed by the compiler, very unlike Java imports for example

Comment: @byde yes that's true, I do understand them but sometimes when your in the process of writing code, you do get so caught up with the thought that you may forget some #include statements. This is just for convenience after all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio by default does not have this functionality. It will be available after installing commercial [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/?fromMenu) plugin:
[image]

Comment: Ah thank you ! Just to confirm, I would need Resharper C++ right ?

Comment: resharper may be free for students.

Comment: @PutsandCalls Maybe it has changed with VS2015, but Community edition probably does not support plugins. So you might need to upgrade edition of VS too, if you want ReSharper.

Comment: Community Edition support plugins. I use it myself at home with Visual Assist.